# jquery do not allow product of two to be more that

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jsfiddel link : https://jsfiddle.net/d6uarv9h/9/

i have two input box lenght and width , these are used to calculate area based on their proportion which works fine.

i want that area (= length * width ) not be more that 1000.

i am unable to to this below is my code:

i am able to show warning once area is more that 1000 but user must not be allowed to input amount that makes area more that 1000

```js
var sizeheight = "1";
var sizewidth ="1.61";

jQuery("#sizewidth").on("input propertychange paste", function() {
    jQuery('#sizeheight').val(((jQuery('#sizewidth').val()*sizeheight)/sizewidth).toFixed(2));
    jQuery('#finalsize').html(jQuery("#sizewidth").val()+" * "+jQuery("#sizeheight").val()+ " inches");
});


jQuery("#sizeheight").on("input propertychange paste", function() {
    jQuery('#sizewidth').val(((sizewidth/sizeheight)*jQuery('#sizeheight').val()).toFixed(2));
    jQuery('#finalsize').html(jQuery("#sizewidth").val()+" * "+jQuery("#sizeheight").val()+ " inches");
}); 





$('#sizewidth,#sizeheight').on('keyup', function(e) {
var myfinalarea = parseFloat(jQuery('#sizewidth').val())*parseFloat(jQuery('#sizeheight').val());
  if (myfinalarea > 1000){
   jQuery('#warning').show();
    /* to add code here */
  }else{ jQuery('#warning').hide(); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sizewidth" value="1.61">
<input type="text" id="sizeheight" value="1">

<span id="finalsize">1.61*1</span>

<span id="warning" style="display:none">area should be less that 1000</span>
```

Comment: a warning: your sizeheight and sizewidth are STRINGS - while javsacript will handle that "internally" with `*`, `/` and `-` (you use `*` and `/`) - you probably won't get what you expect if you ever use `+`

Comment: can not get you my code is working with no errors

Comment: I **did** mention that your code is OK because you only multiply and divide - the only time having these vars as strings can bite you is if you *add* - it was simply a warning, because the code as it stands is not *best practice* - if you don't get it, don't worry ... one day you'll set a `var x = "1.23", y = 4` and wonder why `x + y == "1.234"` ... and you'll remember me

Comment: oh thanks yeah i got that , can you help me with issue

Comment: no, I don't do jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this article](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/restricting-input-with-jquery/).

So in the input event listener, after you've done the calculation, and you realise the total size is greater than your limit, you use `event.preventDefault` to prevent the change from happening.

Comment: i tried to do that but it works after multiple is more that 1000 , can you edit jsfiddel